# How do I merge data from 3 tables into 1 table in powerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have three datatables and three lookup tables in powerBI:

These three are look tables:

tbl_pupils, tbl_year and tbl_term and all look up tables. tbl_maths, tbl_engish and tbl_science all hold test scores and reference the three lookup tables.
[image]

I want to create a table in a report which shows the pupil name with their English, maths and science score for any chosen academic year and term (which would be slicers). However, each pupil may not have a score for each of the three assessments, maybe two or even one. Therefore the table needs to show blank entries for that record if there is no test score.

This is the result I need to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query merge tbl_english and tbl_science on (yearID,termID,pupilID).

tbl_pupils, tbl_year, and tbl_term should stay as separate tables.

The M looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(tbl_science, {"yearID", "termID", "pupilID"}, tbl_english, {"yearID", "termID", "pupilid"}, "tbl_english", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"yearID", "termID", "pupilid"}, tbl_maths, {"yearID", "termID", "pupilid"}, "tbl_maths", JoinKind.Inner)
in
    #"Merged Queries"
```

Comment: we need to create relationships to merged table from tbl_pupils, tbl_year, and tbl_term. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Correct.  You need relationships.

Comment: Yes, they all had relationships defined.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem - whether or not the best way is another matter - by creating a new table using the 'Merge as new' feature and selecting two tables with a full outer join, making sure the academicyear and termID were matching.

I then merged this new table with another table to bring in the third subject.